# $(window).unload is not firing

Tags: jquery, onbeforeunload

I want to execute an action method when the user is abandoning a particular page using jQuery.

The page has the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).unload(function () {
            alert("Handler for .unload() was called.");
        });

    </script>
```

When I navigate away from the page I never see the expected alert.

Comment: Have you tried in other browsers? What browser(s) have you tried it in? The documentation over at the jQuery site is clear with that this event is pretty unstable.

Comment: Unload is deprecated and removed, check this: https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Actually some browsers such as Google Chrome might block if you attempt to `alert` in a window `unload`. As a user I like this feature. Alerting every time you try to navigate away from a page sucks:

[image]

Replace the alert with a `console.log` or something else less intrusive to the user and the event will be happily called.

You might also want to checkout the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the unload event was unstable but I didn't know chrome (which is what I was using) behaves like that.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Replacing alert with a console.log won't give you much useful effect, as console (at least in Chrome) is being cleared, right after you refresh page or navigate to another one. You can see traces of your messages written to console some miliseconds before they actually disappear, so I would rather find it useless. Disabling alert in unload isn't best idea. It is hard to do some serious testings and "awful" pages can do easy workaround by displaying own, "annoying" message, not using alert (jQuery UI, some div, etc.).

Comment: @trejder If you right click in the console in chrome there is an option to preserve log upon navigation

Comment: @Luke: You're right (of course! :])! I've already found this myself. But, thanks anyway...

Comment: @trejder a bit of necromancy, but it's always nice to close some things up for future searchers

Comment: Worth flagging for future searchers that `unload` was deprecated in jQuery v1.8 and removed in v3.0.

Answer (score 21):

jquery .on('unload',..); was not reliable working for me. i switched over to use beforeunload. just make sure you are not returning anything, or the user will get a "are you sure to leave the page"-popup.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
         console.log("beforeUnload event!");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Although, Darin's answer is correct, user's should really refer to this answer. Using "onbeforeunload" not only lets you trigger alerts, but is also recommended and reliable unlike the unload, which, at least for Chrome, is quite buggy.

Answer (score 9):

as bhelm said 
**beforeunload** 
works for me as well.

return false on this event will invoke the browser default

> are you sure you want to leave this page?

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function ()
    {
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In many projects of mine, the **mentioned methods here are instable**. The only thing that **works** for me is to bind the event as **original attribute on the body element**.

```
<body onunload="my_function_unload()">
```

jQuery method:

```
$('body').attr('onunload', 'my_function_unload()');
```

From an iframe:

```
<body onunload="window.parent.my_function_unload()">
```

jQuery method:

```
$('<iframe />').load(function(){
    $body = $(this).contents().find('body');
    $body.attr('onunload', 'window.parent.my_function_unload()');
}
```

Also, **important**, no arguments in the attribute, and the function must be in the global window scope, otherwise nothing happens.

For example, common mistake If your `my_function_unload()` are wrapped inside a `;( function( $ ) {...` OR `$(document).ready(function(){...` AS `my_function_unload()` must be **outside that private scope**. And dont forget to use `jQuery` instead of `$` prefix then.

Comment: So good of an answer.  Looked for this for a long time.

Comment: I don't see how this fires on an actual unload event.  It just fires as soon as the page is loaded; no way to further bind it to a click or any other event.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to alert user that you leaving this page then if this

```html
/* $(window).unload(function()
{
 //alert("you leaving this page");
 console.log("you leaving this page");
}); */
```

function not work for you then replace your code with on("beforeunload",function) like this

```html
$(window).on("beforeunload", function()
{
 alert("you leaving this page");
 console.log("you leaving this page");
});
```

this work for me ! you can see the output in console log 
[you leaving this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOIvY.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload=navigationError;

var dont_confirm_leave = 0; var leave_message = 'You sure you want to leave?';

function navigationError(e) 
  {
    if(dont_confirm_leave!==1)
    {
      if(!e) e = window.event;
      //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      e.returnValue = leave_message;
      //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
      if (e.stopPropagation) 
      {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      }

      //return works for Chrome and Safari
      return leave_message;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar in an iframe, and this is what worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//...
    window.parent.$('iframe[title="Iframe"]')[0].contentWindow.onunload = function() {
    //...
    };
});
```

So, based in the latter, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //...
    window.onunload = function (){
        alert("Handler for .unload() was called.");
    }
}
```

Seems like the «*.on('unload', function()...)*» jQuery method doesn't works as it's expected.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping to 2024+ be aware that `unload` event is being phased out by major browsers

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/deprecating-unload

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event

And also that it has often been unreliable depending on browser version with issues, for example in cross domain context (see this, still open)

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41183357