# how to call a function before page reload jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a few links in my page and I want to call a function when the page is trying to reload.

I tried

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
});
```

It is not working.

Comment: "Not working" in what browser?

Comment: @raina77ow -> google chrome.........

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya: what actions(s) do you want to perform onunload? Also, bear in mind unload is called: "... when the user navigates away from the page... clicked on a link... typed in a new URL... The forward and back buttons [and] ... closing the browser window [and] ... a page reload will first create an unload event." ([Source](http://api.jquery.com/unload)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Console: `Blocked alert('Handler for .unload() called.') during unload.` (in Chrome)

I assume this is blocked for user-experience reasons.

If you try `console.log('Handler for .unload() called.');` the call is made successfully.

Edit: see [$(window).unload is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385778/window-unload-is-not-firing)

Answer (score 4):

you can try:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {

}
```

Comment: hm the problem in this code is iti is asking the user to leave or stay in the page , i don't want , i want a function to be called , but the user should not know that . acctually i am trying to pass some values to the server and save in the session for future use

Answer (score 0):

window.onbeforeunload = unloadMessage;

```
   function unloadMessage() {
           //do your codeing here...
   }
```