# window.unload not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have an anchor tag in my html page which will go to Google when I click. I have a jQuery function which needs to be fired when the page leaves.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    alert('fffffffff');
 });
```

I found this works fine in a video tutorial. But it's not working for me. Using firefox. help

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(window).unload is not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385778/window-unload-is-not-firing)

Comment: Do not use alert,prompt or confirm in unload method

Comment: @shadow prompt and confirm also not working

Answer (score 5):

Its working fine, you just need to remove the `alert`, as some browsers don't allow alert on `unload` event.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
   console.log("hello");
});
```

try this http://jsfiddle.net/vyMdF/

Just run it again and you can check the console.

You can refer over here [$(window).unload is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385778/window-unload-is-not-firing)

Comment: How can i view the console in firefox

Comment: Use F12 and go for Console then All.

Comment: Actually pressing run does not give the output

Comment: That isn't the right answer, you want to hook to `window.onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 5):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you wish to leave the page?";
}
```

Comment: working. I have a doubt. Is this the jquery way? why cant I use this function as $(window).onbeforeunload(function(){return "somthing";});

Comment: @Derek is this pure java script? I am a beginner. help

Comment: @Shameer - Yes this is in pure JavaScript. Just put it in the `<head>` and when you close the window that line will execute.