# How to post data through ajax when brfore browser getting close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have called a javascript function on html unload event but it is only working on google chrome not in firefox and IE.

```
<script>
    function fun()
    {
        $.post("test.php",{name:'name'},function(data){alert(data);})
    }
    </script>

    <body onUnload="fun()">
    </body>**emphasized text**
```

Comment: This has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385778/window-unload-is-not-firing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload). Is supported by Safari, IExplorer, Firefox, Opera and Chrome.

A basic example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onbeforeunload = OnBeforeUnLoad;
            function OnBeforeUnLoad () {
                return "bye world!";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>Close or reload the page.</b>
    </body>
</html>
```