# jquery window.unload not working on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

I want to make an AJAX request on browser close event.

This code does not work on Safari.

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    //my function call;
});
```

The code below works on both Chrome and Safari, but gets fired on page reload as well, which is not desired.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload ',function() {
     //my function call;
 });
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385778/window-unload-is-not-firing) question discusses the onbeforeunload event. Do you have an `alert` in your `onload` function? Not sure what else browsers block.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function ()
    {
        return false;
    });
```

Your `onload` Syntax looks ok to me so not sure of the Jquery issue otherwise. Perhaps try the Javascript equivalent:

```
<element onunload="myScript">
```

or

```
window.onunload=function(){myScript};
```

Comment: I tried both of the suggestions you provided, but they're not getting fired in Safari. Also, I don't want this event to be fired on page refresh, so 'beforeunload' is not of my help here.