# How do I get "unload" to perform tasks within function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get these two pieces of code to behave the same, but they do not :
this one works when button is clicked:

```
 // close button needs to push the locations index to the history
    $('span.close-canvas').on('click', function () {
        history.pushState({}, '', '/locations');
        $('html').removeClass('scrollable-no');
        $('html').removeClass('flyup-visible');
        var titleParts = document.title.split("|");
        document.title = "Locations | " + titleParts[1];
    });
```

this one does not ... it does perform the alert, but nothing else

// Open detail page when clicked

```
$(window).unload = closeBtn();

function closeBtn () {
    alert("refresh button pressed");
    history.pushState({}, '', '/locations');
    $('html').removeClass('scrollable-no');
    $('html').removeClass('flyup-visible');
    var titleParts = document.title.split("|");
    document.title = "Locations | " + titleParts[1];
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload This might be more useful. Run functions before it begins it's unload sequence.

Comment: `$(window).on( "unload", closeBtn );`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(window).unload is not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385778/window-unload-is-not-firing)