# Execute javascript on page unload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello I want to call a JavaScript function when the user clicks the close tab button, back button, a link etc. This is what I have so far:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" 
              language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

                $(window).unload(function(){
                  pageleave();
                });

               if(loged){
                    var Art = "<?php echo $id;?>";
                    var User = "<?php echo $email;?>";
                    var olikes = "<?php echo $Olikes;?>";
                    var odislikes = "<?php echo $Odislikes;?>";
                    var state = "<?php echo $state1; ?>";
                    function pageleave() {
                        $.get("dealLikes.php?article=Art&user=User>&state=1&likes=likes&dislikes=dislikes&Olikes=olikes&Odislikes=odislikes&prev=state");
                        alert("done");
                        return false;
                    }
               }else{}


              </script>
```

The function should then execute a php file. However it dosnt get that far, the page leave function isnt being called, I tested the unload function with an alert and it didnt work. I searched on the internet but nothing would work that i found. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The `unload` event is unreliable at best, and behaviour varies for different browser, and there's never any guarantee that something will actually happen before the client leaves.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but I didn't see that you were using jQuery. That freature was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 3.0

Also this is a duplicate question [$(window).unload is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385778/window-unload-is-not-firing)

The actual way of doing this is like

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Bye now!";
};
```

Anyway I think that in the moment that you perform something that return the control of the program to the js event loop (like your asynchronous request), it will close the window

Comment: I believe you're the one whos mistaken, there is no `window.unload`, it's actually `window.onunload`, but as the OP is using jQuery, `$(window).unload(...` is correct.

Comment: it still isnt working

Comment: Now you're getting somewhere, jQuery 3.1.1 has no `unload` method

Comment: @adeneo yep. My mistake, I edited my answer.