# How to run javascript before page exit?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I just want to send an XHR before the page is unloaded. I've tried using the event listener 'beforeunload', but I've found that it isn't consistent. Is there any other method of executing javascript before exiting the page?

Comment: `beforeunload` isn't consistent, but it's the best we've got

Comment: There's really no way to guarantee it. Consider that the computer itself might be suddenly powered off.

Comment: If its to ensure minimal data loss, the best approach may be to just set up a task to periodically send over any data as if the page could close any second. Google Docs sends data on every change the user makes. Maybe something similar?

Comment: jQuery might be more consistent:  https://api.jquery.com/unload/ or here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385778/window-unload-is-not-firing