# Why is jQuery unload event not executing?

Tags: javascript

I wanna alert the message. Example 1 is working but Example 2 isn't. Everything else like `localStorage.setItem` or `console.log` aren't working in Example 2 too. Why?

**Example 1**

```
$(document).on('unload', alert('Reloaded!'))
```

**Example 2**

```
$(document).on('unload', function (){
  alert('Reloaded!');
});
```

Comment: In the first example, you are not actually passing any callback to the event listener. You're executing the `alert` function, and passing its result (`undefined`) to the event listener. The second one isn't working because thankfully, some browsers [block `alert` on unload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9386675/1913729)

Comment: @blex that's the funny thing because even without the callback it is working BUT example 2 is not..

Comment: @blex maybe they block alerts, but do they block `localStorage.setItem` and `console.log` too? Because they are not working

Comment: Maybe try `$(window).on('unload', /* ... */ )` ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0eya1L7n/))

Comment: Not working too. `localStorage.setItem` and `console.log` work but alert is not working. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.onunload is not working properly in Chrome browser. Can any one help me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794301/window-onunload-is-not-working-properly-in-chrome-browser-can-any-one-help-me)